# Horizontal scroll not working in several devices using dojo mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, scrollable

I'm developing an application using Dojo Mobile 1.8 and for some unknown reason Horizontal scroll is not working on several devices. On Nokia Lumia 620 scroll is not working at all. On two Nexus 5(4.4.2) devices scroll is working really bad, moving by 1-2 millimeters, regardless of how long or far you scroll. On Nexus 5(L) scroll if working perfectly. On Chrome emulator on Desktop, scroll is working perfectly, though sometimes buttons aren't clickable, but I guess that's because Emulator fails to send click/touch events properly.

I've referred to official documentation, but found nothing about why scroll wouldn't work. In some forum, I've found that `touch-action:none` is causing the problem, but that's not the case either, because `touch-action` only has `inherit` and `initial` options.

This is the code that's not working on some devices:

```
<div style="height: 50px; position: fixed; bottom: 50px; width: 1000%; z-index: 2;">
        <ul id="toolbar" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane"
            data-dojo-props="scrollDir:'h', height:'50px'"
            style="position: fixed; bottom: 50px; width: 100%; z-index: 2;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button"
                            id="toolbar-my-location">My Location</button>
                    </td>
                    ...
                    <td>
                        <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button"
                            id="toolbar-full-map">Full Map</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: No. I tried to update dojo to newer version, because 1.8 does not officially support any of those browsers, but my manager told me that updating is not an option.

Comment: Any reason given by the manager for not allowing the newer version?. Anyway did you at least try with the newer version whether it resolve the issue? I do not have the Nexus 5 and lumia 620 ( not that rich) for testing.

Comment: No, I was not allowed to push code into server that runs the application. Also, I have only a Nexus 5, other phones are colleagues'.